# It is hard to me to find Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] angular.js:38

Tags: angularjs

I struggled with this problem a couple of hours. I am new to AngularJs. I try to write a small demo that uploads an image to backend server. Perhaps, I wrote something wrong or made some mistakes that I can not recognize by myself. Can I anyone point out the reason that cause the error?

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myapp">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Upload image test</title>

  </head>

  <body layout="column">


    <div ng-view></div>

    <p>Hello world</p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/angular.js/1.4.4/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myApp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myService.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

myApp.js

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute','$httpProvider']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'myCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'uploadImage.html'
    })
});
app.run(function($httpProvider) 
{
    var auth = atob('xxttww:090909');
    console.log(auth);
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + auth;
});
```

myController.js

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){
            $scope.uploadFile = function(){
               var file = $scope.myFile;

               console.log('file is ' );
               console.dir(file);

               var uploadUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/Image/";
               fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
            };
         }]).directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
            return {
               restrict: 'A',
               link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                  var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
                  var modelSetter = model.assign;

                  element.bind('change', function(){
                     scope.$apply(function(){
                        modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                     });
                  });
               }
            };
      }]);
```

myService.js

```
angular.module('myapp').service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
            this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
               var fd = new FormData();
               fd.append('file', file);

               $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                  transformRequest: angular.identity,
                  headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
               })

               .success(function(){
               })

               .error(function(){
               });
            }
         }]);
```

uploadImage.html

```
html>

   <body>

      <div ng-controller = "myCtrl">
         <input type = "file" file-model = "myFile"/>
         <button ng-click = "uploadFile()">upload me</button>
      </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

Error in detail:

[image]

Comment: I'd be willing to bet it's due to you trying to depend on `$httpProvider` in your app instead of using that in the configuration...

Comment: `$injector:moduleerr` means you trying to inject an invalid module. If you follow the link that angular provided (and the link in subsequent error notifications) it will eventually tell you the problematic module.